# Like with IIF and date range not returning results

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to write an Access query (Access 2013) that uses an IIF statement to first check the value of an Option Frame and then, if the value is "1", use a date range or, if the value is anything else, find all records (only values "1" and "2" are available).  My query criteria is...

```
Like IIf([Forms]![MaintenanceDueList]![OptionFrame]=1,>[Forms]![MaintenanceDueList]![FromDateText] And <[Forms]![MaintenanceDueList]![ToDateText],"*")
```

When my Option Frame Value is set to "2" I get all records returned as expected, but when my Option Frame value is set to "1" I get no results at all, despite there being plenty of records available with dates between the two dates provided in the FromDateText and ToDateText TextBox fields.

This one really has ne stumped, so any help would be gratefully received.  Thanks, Mort640.

Answer (score 0):

`IIF` returns a *value* but you seem to be trying to return some SQL logic - the true/false parts are evaluated then returned.

You can instead:

```
WHERE
    [Forms]![MaintenanceDueList]![OptionFrame] = 2 
OR
    XXX > [Forms]![MaintenanceDueList]![FromDateText] And XXX < [Forms]![MaintenanceDueList]![ToDateText]
```

or to be inclusive of XXX as opposed to greater-than

```
WHERE
    [Forms]![MaintenanceDueList]![OptionFrame] = 2 
OR
    XXX BETWEEN [Forms]![MaintenanceDueList]![FromDateText] And [Forms]![MaintenanceDueList]![ToDateText]
```